# Memory leak using Google.Cloud.Logging.V2 package in C#

Tags: c#, .net, google-app-engine, google-cloud-logging

Using latest Google.Cloud.Logging.V2 package from nuget, 1.0.0

My function for sending logs:

```
private static void WriteLogEntry(string message, Google.Cloud.Logging.Type.LogSeverity severity)
{
    string threadName = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(threadName))
    {
        threadName = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString();
    }

    LogEntry logEntry = new LogEntry
    {
        LogName = logName.ToString(),
        Severity = severity,
        TextPayload = string.Format("[{0}]: {1}", threadName, message)
    };

    CloudLogClient.WriteLogEntriesAsync(LogResource, Monitor, EntryLabels, new[] { logEntry });
}
```

Made a stress test that uses this function to send ~50 logs/sec/thread from 40 threads. That test leaks memory massively, about 100MB/10 minutes of running compared to having the test disabled.

Here is the diff from the memory profiler:
[image: Memory profiler]

This issue also happens when going through the Google.Cloud.Logging.Log4Net package.

Any suggestion on how to further narrow this down would be appreciated. Is there any source code available for the cloud logging package that can be inspected to find the source of the memory leak?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking the versions of the dependencies you are adding through NuGet, as the newer versions have fixed some issues that have caused memory leaks in the past.

If you are using a Grpc.Core older than 1.7.0, there is an issue with the C# cancellation token registration not being unregistered, and therefore causing a memory leak, as seen [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/12800). Later versions of Grpc.Core fixed this issue, so you can try using a newer version of Grpc.Core, which is available in the NuGet Package Manager.

Also, you can update the Log4Net appender to the newest version (2.2.0), which is also available in the NuGet Package Manager. Once you have updated your dependencies, you can try again and check whether there is a memory leak or not.